# Drag and drop to open html page

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag, enter

I am trying to make a drag and drop button on the home page of my website that when i drop the button to the target that open the second page of my website how can i do it ? 
there is my code:

```js
$( init );
 
function init() {
  $('#makeMeDraggable').draggable();
  $('#makeMeDroppable').droppable( {
    drop: handleDropEvent
  } );
}
 
function handleDropEvent( event, ui ) {
  var draggable = ui.draggable;
  alert( 'The square with ID "' + draggable.attr('id') + '" was dropped onto me!' );
}
```

```css
#makeMeDraggable { float: left; width: 300px; height: 300px; background: red; }
#makeMeDroppable { float: right; width: 300px; height: 300px; border: 1px solid #999; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="content" style="height: 400px;">
 
  <div id="makeMeDraggable"> </div>
  <div id="makeMeDroppable"> </div>
 
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2c1nnLtq/

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
window.location.href = "link of your 2nd page";
```

That will change the current location to the assigned href

Comment: i can' t find a solution for put it when my button is on the target :/

Comment: I don't get your problem. Can you use jsfiddle with the button you are saying?